How can I create Thumbnails fast using Flutter and Dart?
I want to be able to create Thumbnails fast for jpg's and png's using only native Flutter and Dart resources (no plugin). Some apps/packages I note are extremely fast at doing this (eg. Aves). I have been able to get the time using my code down to about 300ms per Image, but packages such as aves are much faster. When displaying say 60 Thumbnails, 300 ms takes about 20 seconds whereas Aves is about 1 or 2 seconds. Currently I am using dart:ui to resize the image and when it has been resized I use Paint to create the Widget and then I display it using Container with BoxDecoration and DecorationImage at which time it has been resized. The original image sizes are generally about 2 to 3 mb on Android.
Using Flutter components to do the resize is from my experience too slow. I am displaying the thumbnails progressively, so the time taken is not so obvious, but when compared to eg. Aves, the difference is very noticeable. As I said, I can only use Flutter and Dart resources and no external packages. As far as I know, Aves creates the Thumbnails and I believe that there are no Thumbnails in the Exif data on at least one phone tested. All of the images tested are jpg's.
